# Infinite Integer in Java

Tags: java

I don't think I'm approaching this the right way. I'm supposed to create a class that allows users to enter in any number not matter how big it is (Of course, with the restrictions of memory it's not really infinite). I have some code but I'm pretty sure the quality is crap. I seem to be having the most trouble with a string and have been avoiding it. I'll only post what I have worked on. I just need help clearing it up because I don't think I'm going in the right direction. Here is what my code has so far. I apologize. I'm not a very seasoned coder.:

```
public class InfiniteInteger implements Comparable<InfiniteInteger> {
    // TO DO: Instance Variables

    public final int BigNumbers;
    public final String Infinite;
    public final int []integerArray;

    public InfiniteInteger(String s) {
        // TO DO: Constructor

        Infinite=s;
    }

    public InfiniteInteger(int anInteger) {
        // TO DO: Constructor

        BigNumbers=anInteger;
        integerArray= new int[anInteger];
    }

    public int getNumberOfDigits() {
        // TO DO: return an integer representing the number of digits
        of this infinite integer. //

       int NumberOfDigits=0;

       for(int i=0; NumberOfDigits<0;i++){

       }

       return BigNumbers;
   } 

   /**
    * Checks whether this infinite integer is a negative number.
    * @return true if this infinite integer is a negative number.
    * Otherwise, return false.
    */
   public boolean isNegative() {
       // TO DO

       if(isNegative()) {
           return true;
       } else return false;
   }
```

Do I need to convert the string to `int` in my first constructor. I also had made an   array previously in the string constructor but it caused a whole lot of grief so I got rid of it and just put one in the second constructor.

Comment: There's already a [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) type that does what you want.

Comment: Use `BigInteger` instead. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: Your `isNegative` method will never work, since you call the method in your own method with no stopcondition... Resulting in infinite recursion

Comment: Re, "with the restrictions of memory it's not really infinite":  With a high-end PC, you should be able to handle larger numbers than a person could type into the computer in his/her lifetime.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `BigInteger` for that. It uses an bitarray with varying length.

Operations on `BigInteger`'s are slower but will work, regardless of the number (as long as it is an integer). And furthermore `BigInteger` operations are optimized (for instance using special CPU instructions)...

On a sidenote if people mean *any number*, they sometimes mean *any resonable number*. In that case the range of a `long` is in many cases sufficient.

Comment: I'm not allowed to import java.math. Unless I don't have to?

Comment: yes. We can use an array but no lists,bags,or any data structures.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Java built-in class [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), from the Javadoc `BigInteger` is for

> Immutable arbitrary-precision integers.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The answer to the question is "No. You would never use a String like this."

Comment: @MikkelLøkke Sounds like [this constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String%29) to me.

Comment: @MikkelLøkke I've seen no question mark in the OP's post, so there's technically no question anyway ^^

Comment: @ElliottFrisch From what I can see that doesn't convert a string, containing a number which could potentially be larger than Integer.MAXVALUE into an int. Which is how I understand the "question". If your home-made `BigInteger` uses a `String` representation, but is still confined to the limitations of a basic `int`, once you need it for any type of arithmetic, using a `String` to represent interim values is pointless and redundant.

Comment: @MikkelLøkke Yes, but if you use Oracle's `BigInteger` you can construct it with a `String`. Which is (I think) what OP is trying to do.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch So can `Integer`, and almost every other subclass of `Number`. I fail to see how this is relevant to the question asked. Which was not about either of those two.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish is already made in BigInteger class. Maybe examining it's source might be useful when creating a simpler version of it :

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigInteger.java

Comment: Yes and this would be useful if I were allowed to import java.math for it but I cannot. Unless I don't need to?....import anything that is to use BigInteger?